# Using the Chain Rule

Tags: calculus

Find $dy/dx$. $y=x/\sqrt{x^2+1}$. I started with the quotient rule and got $y'=(x^2+1)^{1/2}-x^2(x^2+1)^{1/2 }$all over $((x^2+1)^{1/2})^2$. I can not find my mistake.

Comment: Check your computation of the derivative of $(x^2 + 1)^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Quotient rule:  $\left(\dfrac{f}{g}\right)'=\dfrac{f'g-fg'}{g^2}$.

In this case: $f=x$, $f'=1$, $g=(x^2+1)^{1/2}$.  Use the chain rule to find $g'$, which is $g'=\frac12(x^2+1)^{-1/2}(x^2+1)'=\frac12(x^2+1)^{-1/2}(2x).$  Now put this all together to determine

$\left(\dfrac{f}{g}\right)'.$

Answer (score 0):

Another way: 
Product rule

\begin{align*}
y' = [x(x^2+1)^\frac{-1}{2}]' &= x\frac{-1}{2}(x^2+1)^\frac{-3}{2}(2x) + 1(x^2+1)^\frac{-1}{2}\\
&= -x^2(x^2+1)^\frac{-3}{2} + (x^2+1)^\frac{-1}{2}\\
&= \frac{-x^2}{(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}+ \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^\frac{1}{2}}\\
&= \frac{-x^2}{(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}+ \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^\frac{1}{2}}\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+1}\\
&= \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^\frac{3}{2}}
\end{align*}